# Wordpress taxonomia inválida

Tags: php, wordpress

Comecei um projeto recentemente e não consigo "linkar" meus posts com minhas taxonomias, meu código:

```
$argsProjeto = array(
    'post_type' => 'projetos',
    'orderby'     => 'post_date',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
);

$projetos = get_posts($argsProjeto);

$argss = array(
    'orderby'  => '
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy' => 'tax_projetos',
);

$tax = get_terms($projetos[0]->ID, $argss);

var_dump($tax);
```

Como retorno, o `var_dump` mostra:

> ```
> object(WP_Error)[5371]
>   public 'errors' => 
>     array (size=1)
>       'invalid_taxonomy' => 
>         array (size=1)
>           0 => string 'Taxonomia inválida.' (length=20)
>   public 'error_data' => 
>     array (size=0)
>       empty
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar os posts da taxynomia precisa passar dessa forma:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'tax_projetos', 'hide_empty' => false ) ); ?>
<?php foreach( $terms as $_terms ):

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'projetos',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tax_projetos',
                'field'    => 'slug', // tipo do valor que vc vai passar no terms
                'terms'    => $_terms->slug // slug da categoria, esse slug é gerado quando vc  cria a categoria nova em uma taxynomia
            )
        )
    );
endforeach;
        $postslist = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: ainda ta me retornando vazio, pode ser um erro de hook?

Comment: teste dessa forma